# From where date() is returned

Tags: php, date, datetime

This question might seem low rated but I did not get the answer so I am asking. 
In php, there is a function `date()`. But when I try to get `date()`, is it returned from my server or client side?

Edit: I was stupid when I asked this question. I had apache running on my own PC. So both server and client dates were the same.

Answer (score 0):

Should be server side because you know php runs server side!

Comment: Or not? I have a piece of code which inserts data in database as per date. But today I saw that it cannot get the data of today.

Comment: Then there's something else going on @AdityaGiri - `date()` formats a unix timestamp as a displayable date; if you don't give it a unix timestamp argument, then it defaults to getting the current unix timestamp from the server where the code is executing.... it doesn't touch a database, so if you're getting a different value  in a database, you must have some other code

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `date()` returns server date, because web browser don't send any data which can determine user's local time.

If you want to get user's local time you have two ways to do that:

- Use JavaScript and send output to the server using POST/AJAX/Whatever.
- Less accurate - IP Address. You can get user's ISP location and timezone of it. But sometimes IP Address returns totally different location.

Anyway, in my opinion the best solution to the store date with different time zones, is storing also user defined timezone (for example, when user is registered, or in UCP), and dates directly in London (UTC) time.